# Dalvik crash on Oneplus on Android 12

Tags: android, crashlytics, dalvik, moshi, crashlytics-android

I've got an app in the play store, and have just started seeing the following crash on crashlytics as we're releasing a new version:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class app.models.basket.BasketPrice: app.models.pricing.Money app.models.basket.BasketPrice.component1() failed to verify: app.models.pricing.Money app.models.basket.BasketPrice.component1(): [0x2] return-wide not expected
app.models.pricing.Money app.models.basket.BasketPrice.component2() failed to verify: app.models.pricing.Money app.models.basket.BasketPrice.component2(): [0x2] return-wide not expected
app.models.pricing.Money app.models.basket.BasketPrice.component3() failed to verify: app.models.pricing.Money app.models.basket.BasketPrice.component3(): [0x2] return-wide not expected (declaration of 'app.models.basket.BasketPrice' appears in /data/app/~~SMvMJ3wjLcBZoO_7ATEdrA==/app-MRhsaTqPRxyDfq-Ma3jNMA==/base.apk)
       at app.models.basket.BasketPriceJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketPriceJsonAdapter.kt:53)
       at app.models.basket.BasketPriceJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketPriceJsonAdapter.kt:21)
       at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:41)
       at app.models.basket.BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionJsonAdapter.kt:57)
       at app.models.basket.BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionJsonAdapter.kt:22)
       at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:41)
       at app.models.basket.BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionsJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionsJsonAdapter.kt:37)
       at app.models.basket.BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionsJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketPricedFulfilmentOptionsJsonAdapter.kt:20)
       at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:41)
       at app.models.basket.BasketResponseJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketResponseJsonAdapter.kt:79)
       at app.models.basket.BasketResponseJsonAdapter.fromJson(BasketResponseJsonAdapter.kt:24)
       at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:41)
       at app.models.DataWrapperJsonAdapter.fromJson(DataWrapperJsonAdapter.kt:44)
       at app.models.DataWrapperJsonAdapter.toJson(DataWrapperJsonAdapter.kt:22)
       at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:41)
       at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:46)
       at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

I can't find anyone with this same `return-wide not expected` issue anywhere on the internet, although the `VerifyError` thing seems to be when the Dalvik runtime runs into issues.

My theory at the moment is that this is just a device specific issue for Oneplus Android 12 devices, but the stacktrace is in our(/Moshi) code, and it seems to only be on the new version, so I feel like there's some kind of aggravating factor. Can anyone say why this is happening?